# angular - setValue formArrayName

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form that has an array of string, every time i add an element to the list, the problem is that when i use setValue to set values in the array, it displays the below error

```
<button (click)="addNewCompany()">Add new Company</button><br><br>
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div formArrayName="companies">
        <div *ngFor="let comp of getForm(); let i=index>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                    <h3>COMPANY {{i+1}}: </h3>
                </legend>
                <label>Company Name: </label>
                <input [formControlName]="i" /><span><button (click)="deleteCompany(i)">Delete Company</button></span>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div><br>
  </form>


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  public product: Product; 

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      companies: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.addNewCompany();
     this.myForm.controls['companies'].setValue(this.product.companies); // error
  }

  getForm(): any {
    return this.myForm.get("companies")["controls"];
  }

  addNewCompany() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.get("companies");
    control.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }

  deleteCompany(index) {
    let control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.companies;
    control.removeAt(index);
  }

}
```

> ERROR Error:    There are no form controls registered with this array
>   yet.  If you're using ngModel,   you may want to check next tick (e.g.
>   use setTimeout).

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gr8ghs)

Comment: Try like this  `this.myForm.patchValue({companies:this.product.companies});`

Comment: try set value inside ngOnChanges() method instead of ngOnInit method

Comment: I don't really think whatever you're trying to do here is going to be scalable enough. That reminds me. What exactly are you trying to do here? Why are you sending the product as a `@input` property to the child component? Can the child component get the `product` via a service instead?

Comment: You are getting this error because you haven't assigned any value to the product field. Assuming this is the root component you don't need @Input decorator here also.

Comment: check this demo base of my answer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccjffb

Comment: before you assaing a value to the formArray you have to have an  control base of the values just run a for or will do the job

Comment: in case you are using a child component I have create answer base of that you can check it also , hope this will solve your problem

Comment: hi , have you check any of the answers?? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you try to set the `companies` from control the value must be an array and make sure you add new form control base of the array value

```
product = {
companies:['company 01' , 'company 02']
}
```

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // make sure you have set a default value to product like {companies:[]}
  for (let p of this.product.companies) {
    this.addNewCompany();
  }

  this.myForm.controls['companies'].setValue(this.product.companies);
}
```

> if you use **setValue** method you have to provide a value base of the controls length otherwise will throw an error in case of the array controls length are less or more the array value must be same length as controls length.
>
> **patchValue** don't have this **constraine** about controls length but this mean if you set companies of 10 and you have just one control you only will get the first company and the other will gone so in that case make sure you use setValue or patchValue but make sure you have a controls of length same as the value

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahjfgs)

Answer (score 0):

You could move the logic of creating the `form` inside `ngOnInit`. Something like this:

```
@Input()
public product: Product;

myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    companies: this.fb.array(this.product ? this.product.companies.map(company => new FormControl(company)) : [])
  });
}

addNewCompany() {
  this.companies.push(new FormControl());
}

deleteCompany(i) {
  this.companies.removeAt(i);
}

get companies() {
  return ( < FormArray > this.myForm.get('companies'));
}
```

---

But there's probably no guarantee that the `product` `@Input` property would be set by the time.

So in order to make sure that it is set before you've created the `form` with `companies` `FormArray`, you might want to initialize the `product` property in it via a service instead.

You'll have to create a `DataService` that does it for you:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product.model';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  product: Product;

  constructor() { }

  setProduct(product) {
    this.product = product;
  }

}
```

You could then inject it in the Parent Component to set the `product` and in the child component to get the product in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook method. Something like this:

```
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private dataService: DataService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    companies: this.fb.array(this.dataService.product ? this.dataService.product.companies.map(company => new FormControl(company)) : [])
  });
}

addNewCompany() {
  this.companies.push(new FormControl());
}

deleteCompany(i) {
  this.companies.removeAt(i);
}

get companies() {
  return ( < FormArray > this.myForm.get('companies'));
}
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-with-initialized-form-controls?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: good answer but still don't look different from my answer  , the main problem he must has a controls base of the value of the data we need to clarify this 

Comment: I updated my StackBlitz Code to take the `product` from a `DataService` instead of using the `@Input` property. Like I mentioned in **[my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59469780/angular-setvalue-formarrayname/59470266?noredirect=1#comment105118834_59469780)**, there's no gurantee that the `product` would be initialized at the time `ngOnInit` is called on the component. And it could be expensive to write this logic in `ngOnChanges` as it gets called every time an `@Input` property changes. Hence the suggestion to get it from the service instead. I'll update my answer shortly.